# If $\omega$ is a differential $4$-form on a $10$-manifold $M$ then $\omega \wedge d\omega$ is exact

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Let $\omega$ be a differential $4$-form on a $10$-manifold $M$. I am trying to show that $\omega \wedge d\omega $, which is  a $9$-form, is exact.

Clearly $\omega \wedge d\omega$ is closed, because $d\omega \wedge d\omega =0$ ($|d\omega|=5$ is odd). But how can we show that $\omega \wedge d\omega $ is exact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** What is $d(\omega \wedge \omega)$?

Comment: @probably123 by the way, the same proof of exactness works for any even degree form $\omega$ (regardless of the dimension of $M$)

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: What is $d(\omega\wedge\omega)$?

Comment: I think it's the first time this happened to me ;)

Comment: @peek-a-boo LOL, you copycat! Sorry :) You can get credit.